# GnuPG 2.2 refuses secret key import: "error sending to agent: operation cancelled"

Tags: gnupg, import, gpg-agent

I'm trying to import my PGP identity including secret keys to a new computer by connecting to a computer which has the secret key, and running

```
ssh othercomputer cat myself.gpg | gpg2 --import
```

When doing this, it looks like GPG is importing the public keys, but not the private ones. When examining the output closer, I can see that it says "error sending to agent: operation cancelled" which I assume has something to do with the problem.

I have

- tried specifying a `pinentry-program` in `gpg-agent.conf`;
- restarted `gpg-agent` and triple-checked it is running; and
- verified that the versions of gpg-agent and gpg match.

Answer (score 2):

The issue – I think – is that GnuPG detects that it is running in a pipe, i.e. in a *non-interactive shell*. Since non-interactive means there's no user interacting with it, there is little point in showing a pinentry dialog – at least in most cases.

The easiest solution is to store `myself.gpg` on the local drive and then import it in a separate command. I understand this solution may have some repercussions in terms of privacy and secrecy, so do understand the consequences of this choice before you blindly follow advice.

Comment: A similar issue occurs when trying to import password-protected private key via pipe from paperkey.

Comment: @kqr that is true, and the solution is to use a text-based pinentry, like `pinentry-curses`. You might have it already installed, but another pinentry program is the default one. On Debian you can `sudo update-alternatives --config pinentry` to set the ncurses version as default. This is usually a symlink from `/usr/bin/pinentry` -> `/etc/alternatives/pinentry` -> `/usr/bin/pinentry-curses`.

Comment: @goetzc Thanks, this helped me out today!

Answer (score 0):

Set `pinentry-mode` on the command line or in the ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf file.

`--pinentry-mode loopback`

or just

`pinentry-mode loopback` in the config file.

Answer (score -1):

Adding `pinentry-mode loopback` in the `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` file works for Ubuntu 20.04